# Check if a string array contains a number of words from an EditText and display them in the order that they were written

Tags: java, android, string

I want to Check if every word typed in an EditText box is present in my string array, Then display them according to the order they were typed.

```
public void superStars(){
    EditText ed =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed);
    String edText = ed.getText().toString();
    String[] stars = {"randy","roman","styles","dean","brock","cena","asylum","phenomenal","cenation","bull dog","suplex city","viper","beats","and","one"};
    if(Arrays.asList(stars).contains(edText)){
        // Toast the output
    }
}
```

Now, let's say the user inputs "asylum beats cenation and the phenomenal one."
I want to make a Toast starting from the first word "asylum" then the second "beats" etc.
Ask me if you need more explanation. 
Thanks.

Comment: Here, it isn't a site to make your homework.

Answer (score 1):

```
  String[] myarray = { "randy","roman","styles","dean","brock","cena","asylum","phenomenal","cenation","bull dog","suplex city","viper","beats","and","one" };

  String s = editText.getText().toString();   
  String[] arr = s.split(" ");   

  for ( String ss : arr) { 
      if (Arrays.asList(myarray).contains(ss)) 
       {
          //your Toast display here
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ss, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 EditText ed =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed);
String edText = ed.getText().toString();
String[] stars = {"randy","roman","styles","dean","brock","cena","asylum","phenomenal","cenation","bull dog","suplex city","viper","beats","and","one"};
for (int i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
        if (stars[i].equals(edText)) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "match string", 5000);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "code not found", 5000);
        }
```